# How to modify base url to display multiple images from the web in iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a web page that has over 100 images uploaded on it namely 1.jpg,2.jpg....100.jpg. I am wondering how can i display these images in a UITableView using the url. The url needs to be changed for every image. For example www.example.com/1.jpg to www.example.com/2.jpg and so on.

Comment: You have only one UIImageView and in that load all the 100 images? Can you please explain your question properly.

Comment: I want to  use table view with 100 rows to display each images from the base url

Answer (score 0):

For downloading image and set image to the imageView, use [SDWebImage](https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage)

let there is a tableview, containing imageView, then set

```
imageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: "YOUR_IMAGE_URL_STRING"), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder.png"))
```

In cell for row at indexPath

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! MyTableViewCell
        let row = indexPath.row + 1
        let imageSuffix = "/\(row).jpg"
        if let url = URL(string : BASE_URL + imageSuffix) {
            cell.imageView.sd_setImage(with: url, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder.png"))
        }
        return cell
    }
```

Comment: There is more than one image. How can i modify the url within the code to display next image

Answer (score 0):

You can use SDWebImage for image loading and caching.
And if your image is having a specific sequence `1.jpg,2.jpg....100.jpg` you can use the below code to make it partial dynamic in tableView.

```
let imageUrl = "www.example.com/\(indexpath.row+1).jpg"
```

And set this user to image view with the help of SDWebImage

```
self.imgview.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: imageUrl), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "avatar.png"))
```